# In ASP.NET CORE application EF Core library do not return new inserted record's ID from database?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-web-api

I had asp.net webapi project where below query was working fine
which is adding data into database and return newly added ID after `_context.SaveChanges()`

> I'm using MYSQL database. It must have to work in MYSQL too :(

but when I migrate `asp.net webapi code to asp.net CORE using EF CORE` new record inserted into database successfully but after `_context.SaveChanges()` it returns 0 as newId  instead new Id .

```
public partial class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
       }


Student student = new Student()
student.name = "test";

_context.Add(student);
_context.SaveChanges()

int newID = student.Id ;
```

//got auto generated Id in asp.net webapi but in asp.net core project it is 0.

any clue ?

Comment: Please include the source code for `Student`.

Comment: added into question pls check

Comment: What is the primary key for the `Student` entity? If you say nothing about it, it will be `Id`, but from the error you're getting, could it be the `name` property instead? You can observe the logs, by calling `AddConsole` and `AddDebug` in `ConfigureServices`.

Comment: Primary key is `Id` which is auto generated field.
No error is there but only issue is I do not get that new inserted Id back , when I used asp.net core with EF core

Comment: I have a same issue. I am using a ASP NET CORE 2 and EF 2, with MariaDB database. The connector is Pomelo version 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't repro for me with either EF Core 1.2 or 2.0.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp8
{

    public partial class Student
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }



    public class Db : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Server=localhost;database=EfCoreTest;Integrated Security=true;MultipleActiveResultsets=false");
            base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
        }

    }
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {            

            using (var db = new Db())
            {
                db.Database.EnsureDeleted();
                db.Database.EnsureCreated();

                Student student = new Student();
                student.name = "test";

                db.Add(student);
                db.SaveChanges();

                int newID = student.Id;
                Console.WriteLine($"NewID {newID}");
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit.");
            Console.ReadKey();


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using MYSQL database. It must have to work in MYSQL too :( – Neo 1 hour ago

Comment: I have no idea about MySQL.  Does this repro not work with MySQL?

Comment: Its working good , record is also added into database table but always getting Id as 0 after  db.SaveChanges(); int newID = student.Id;
Dont know why :(

Answer (score 1):

I was have a same issue. In my case, I used a Database First.
My scaffold was marked to use Data anotation.

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Host=localhost;Port=3306;Database=dbtest;Usernt=root;Password=mypass" -o "Entities" Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -c "DatabaseRepository" -f -d
```

Even marking as "data anotation", some FluentAPI scripts were generated in the onModelCreate method within the context.

```
modelBuilder.Entity<MyEntity>(entity =>
        //{
        //    entity.Property(e => e.Id).ValueGeneratedNever();
        //});
```

Verify if you have a similar code, that set ValueGeneratedNever in the Id property. Change to ValueGeneratedOnAdd

How I am using a data anotation instead FluentAPI, I remove the code inside onModelCreate method.

Using one of the two options, should work.